# Underline will not save using TinyMCE and Ice NYTimes plugin

Tags: tinymce, underline, ice-js

I am using the ice plugin for TinyMCE by the NY Times. It is a great track changes plugin. The problem is that it seems to interfere with the regular underline behavior of TinyMCE. I can underline text, but upon saving that text, the underline is removed.

Bold is appropriately saved as:

```
<p><strong>uuuuuuu</strong></p>
```

Italics is saved as:

```
<p><em>uuuuuuu</em></p>
```

But underline is saved as:

```
<p><span>uuuuuuu</span></p>
```

Finally, no style is saved as:

```
<p>uuuuuuu</p>
```

So for some reason the style:"underline" is being stripped from the span tag. Removing ice fixes the problem, but we need track changes. Any help would be great!